# Doctrine 2 OneToOne Unidirectional doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have the following `OneToOne` relation inside `MyEntity`:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="StatusHistory")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lastest_status_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $lastestStatus;
```

The entity `StatusHistory` works. The `migrations:diff` command creates the files prefectly, and the database have the correct column.

The problem is, when I do `die("c: " . $this->lastestStatus)` inside `MyEntity` (trying to debug a getter), it returns `Namespace\MyEntity` rather than `Namespace\StatusHistory`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I forgot to add the `->join('myEntity.lastestStatus', 'lastestStatus')` clause on the query builder...